# Why does using proportion DV (vs. count) change the results?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, quasi-likelihood

I'm running a regression model using a count variable as the DV and I'm trying to understand what changes when using it as a count outcome vs. a proportion.

REF: https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter19.html

For example,

```r
cuse <- read.table("https://grodri.github.io/datasets/cuse.dat", 
                   header = TRUE)

Intusingfit <- glm(cbind(using, notUsing) ~ age*education, data=cuse, 
                   family=quasibinomial()) 
summary(Intusingfit)

cuse$total <- cuse$using + cuse$notUsing
Intusingfit2 <- glm(using/total ~ age*education, data=cuse, 
                    family=quasibinomial()) 
summary(Intusingfit2)
```

My model basically looks like the first model here, and I wasn't sure what the difference is between that and the second model that uses the proportion of the 'Yes's over the total as the DV.

The dispersion parameter of the DV looks very different in the two approaches and I'm wondering if that's why, and which approach would be recommended (in what contexts).

Comment: Your code `attach(cuse)`  is totally superfluos and possible harmful, so I removed it. Please dont use it (warned against in MASS more than twenty years ago).

Answer (score 2):

When fitting a binomial GLM with proportions you need to pass the total counts via the `weights` parameter:

```r
Intusingfit2 <- glm(using/total  ~ age*education, data=cuse, 
    family=quasibinomial(),
    weights = cuse$total)
```

This model is exactly the same as your first model.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!